# base64 encode image host url or server file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

When I encode image data to a base64 string I use the server file path to get the image data with `fs.readFile()`. I have question: does this mean other people can decode the base64 string then get the server path from the encoded data as below?

```
...
fs.readFile(destinationFilePath, function(error, data){
  fulfill(data.toString('base64'));
});
```

I don't want to leak my server path to so I also tried encode the host url like below code, I'm not sure this correct way to use base64?  and I don't get any error but also I got no response - did I miss something?

```
var base64EncodeData = function(destinationFilePath) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
      var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
      request.get(destinationFilePath, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
          console.log(data);
          fulfill(data);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: If you encode anything like this you can copy the path encryption and decode it. If you look on google you will find many websites that will encode/decode. If for whatever reason someone wants to find the path it can be done in seconds. https://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** you don't leak your server path by base64 encoding images. The base64 you are generating only includes a base64 representation of the binary image data. Indeed by base64 encoding them you remove any use of a path when you display them within a HTML page for example:

`<img alt="base64 image" src="data:image/png;base64,isdRw0KGgot5AAANdSsDIA..." />`

The src attribute contains a flag that data is being provided `data:` the file mimetype `image/png;` the encoding `base64,` and the encoded image data `isdRw0KGgot5AAANdSsDIA...`.

Comment: so it means encoding the image binary data not encoding the  image path, right?

Comment: David, I think the op wants to know if the client can decode the base64 to get the original path. *does that means other people can decode the base64 string then get the server path*

Comment: exactly. When you call `fs.readFile` you are asking for the data at the path location to be converted to a base64 string, not the path itself: `data.toString('base64')`. If you were encoding the path it would be `destinationFilePath.toString('base64')`. But just to let you know once more the data returned by fs.readFile does not contain this information in the `data` variable.

Comment: @NewToJS maybe I misunderstood thanks for clarifying

Comment: @user1775888 thats awesome. as NewToJS said in his comment you can always check if there is any text content encoded in your base64 by using a tool like http://base64decode.org

Comment: @user1775888 to be honest anyone who knows a little javascript wouldn't need to open that link. The client can use the browser console to decode it. **Example:** `atob('aHR0cDovL3d3dy5oZHdhbGxwYXBlcnNpbWFnZXMuY29tL3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE0LzAxL1dpbnRlci1UaWdlci1XaWxkLUNhdC1JbWFnZXMuanBn');`

Comment: @DavidAnderton  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @NewToJS  I don't get it if not include the path than I think there nothing worried about decode right?

Comment: @user1775888 I think I've got the issue now. If you include the base64 in the img src attribute on the page load you have not accessed anything while loading that image (so no one would know where that base64 was generated). **however** all requests to external services can be viewed in the `network` tab of most modern browser inspector consoles (just hit refresh and it will populate with all requests). So I don't believe there is an effective way to hide requests unless you were to route requests through a domain alias.

Comment: @DavidAnderton  ?? but I test on chrome refresh it still show only the base64 code,  not see any further info related file path

Comment: then that would imply you are doing it right :) and not loading the base64 over ajax. You cant hide the ajax request details was what I was trying to say.

Comment: I was doing ajax too , ajax  send the and get the response base64 code to append in dom src

Comment: okay so the ajax request address cant be hidden. although the path where the image was loaded from on your server will be hidden. I just want to make sure that its totally clear :)